# Should I cast my view to UIViewController in my presenter on iOS in a MVP pattern?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, mvp

In a MVP structured iOS app, very often I would need to call some functions in UIViewController class in my Presenter.

For example, an UI event is triggered and my presenter has done some business logic and decide to do one or some of the following UI updates

- Hide back button
- Update Navigation bar title
- Pop up an UIAlertController

It's a lot easier and tidier to do the following

```
func didClickAButton() {
    //Some business logic
    let vc = mUI as! UIViewController
    vc.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    vc.title = "New Title"
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Than creating a protocol function for every functions of UIViewController class that I'm possibly need.

My question is what would be a good way to handling this.

**Edit**:
Maybe I wasn't clear about my question, so the below code should explain it better

```
protocol ViewProtocol {
    func hideBackButton()
    //Potientially one protocol function for each UIViewController's
    //function I might need
    }

class Presenter {
    weak var mUI: ViewProtocol

    func updateUIAfterSomeLogic() {
        //At this point, I can do
        mUI.hideBackButton()
        //or cast mUI to UIViewController because I know it will always 
        //be a subclass of UIViewController
        let vc = mUI as! UIViewController
        vc.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }
}

class View: UIViewController, ViewProtocol {
    func hideBackButton() {
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only kind of object that you should be sending UIViewController messages to is an object that **is** a UIViewController. If you have some other type of object like a Presenter that implements some of the methods of `UIViewController` but is not a view controller then you should not cast it to a `UIViewController`.

If your `mUI` object is a subclass of `UIViewController` then it already **is** a `UIViewController` and there's no reason to cast it to that type.

So no, the code you posted does not seem useful, and if your `mUI` object is not a subclass of `UIViewController` then it's more than unhelpful, it's a bad idea.

### EDIT:

If mUI is always a ViewController, make it a ViewController that conforms to your protocol:

```
var mUI: UIViewController & ViewProtocol
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. See me edits for clarification of my question.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of the edit. To the Presenter, the `mUI` (I just name it `view`) should only be a protocol. It shouldn't know anything more about it. The thought experiment that helps me is to ask, how would I implement it with a terminal-based UI instead of using UIKit?

Comment: Good point @JonReid Stepping back from the details of the OPs question, why does mUI need to be a view controller at all? Better to make it an abstract object conforming to a protocol that the presenter understands.